# can sql send event to node application?

Tags: sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Some resource is create new row in some table on my database.

Is it possible notify to my node application (like event) when this is happends? to connect with the database I use `sequelize.js`. not sure if that's matters.

any ideas will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand your question, I am assuming you're looking to listen for when a row has been inserted into a table.

**The short and probably most "correct" answer is:** no you can't.

**The longer answer is:** you can... *but it probably won't be pretty or efficient*.

### Checking Row Counts In SQL

All you will simply need to do here is keep track of the the current rows that exist in your table, create an interval loop that queries your SQL table to see how many rows it has. From there you will know if it changed. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable` is the SQL statement you want to use.

Given that your primary key also auto-increments, you won't need to do MUCH in order to find what was added to the table. If not, you will need to cache your table in your application, loop through and find the odd record out. Not efficient what so over.

See below for a more intuitive approach to this that doesn't require caching.

### SQL Triggers & Checking Tables

SQL Triggers are probably your best bet. If the table you want to listen to is a "users" table for example, you will define a trigger for "users" when a record is inserted to add to a separate table called "users_update" where it adds a row with the information that references to the "users" table.

In your Node application, you will need to write some code that checks the "users_update" table to see if anything was added to the table at intervals. From there handle it and delete it from the table so you don't handle it again and then you will know when stuff has been added to your users table.

Here is a [good reference to learn how to make triggers](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx). Triggers are a bit tricky but once you learn how to add to a new table, you're set to use this method.

I recommend this if you want ease-of-setup and somewhat efficient use of your SQL database and Node app.

### SQL Triggers & Running External Application & Using Sockets

Another less resource intensive is to launch an external NodeJS application from the command line using SQL triggers. If [you look at the accepted answer here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/688ec345-813e-4028-a7b1-1839e4af9d7b/call-a-dll-or-exe-file-from-sql-trigger?forum=sqlnetfx) you will see that you can call an external EXE file from it. You will need to call the NodeJS executable and then pass in the path to your secondary NodeJS app that connects to your NodeJS application over a socket ([example included](https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757)). You will then use SQL to pass in arguments to your secondary NodeJS application with the data you want it to send to your primary application. Your primary NodeJS application will simply wait for a socket message so you can handle the data as you want. **This is probably way more work than it is worth unless you actually require somewhat efficient communication of updates of SQL**

---

I am not entirely sure if there is a module that exists out there that you can use with your NodeJS application to add triggers, but I am sure if you dug deep enough, someone somewhere, you will find a module that will do what you need to do.

Sorry if I didn't provide any real examples for you. Your question is a little complex to give a direct solution to.